# how to get epochMillis from a date based on timezone

Tags: android, kotlin, epoch, localdatetime

I am trying to get epochMillis from a date based on timezone "Europe/London"

I have a Date `2022-08-31` and I want to get epochMillis for end of day - `2022-08-31T23:59:59`

```
val endOfYear = `2022-08-31`
val format = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
val endDate = format.parse(endOfYear).toLocalDateTime(timeZoneId).plusDays(1).minusSeconds(1) // to get end of that day
//timeZoneId - Europe/London

val epochMillisEnd = epochTimeSecsToMillis(endDate.utcEpochSecs) // returns 1661990399000
```

that returned as shown in the picture.
as per my `timezone` I should receive - Wednesday, 31 August 2022 23:59:59
[image]

// function toLocalDateTime

```
fun Dates.toLocalDateTime(timeZoneId: ZoneId): LocalDateTime {
    return Instant.ofEpochMilli(time).atZone(timeZoneId).toLocalDateTime()
}

val LocalDateTime.utcEpochSecs: Long
    get() = this.toEpochSecond(UTC)

fun epochTimeSecsToMillis(epochTimeInSecs: Long): Long {
    return epochTimeInSecs * 1000
}
```

could you please suggest where I am getting this wrong

Thanks
R

Comment: Not answering your question, I strongly recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Just stick to [java.time, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) exclusively.

Comment: Your first problem is with your use of `SimpleDateFormat`, you don’t know which time zone it is using. Next for converting your Europe/London based date you call your `utcEpochSecs()`? Isn’t that bound to give a wrong result?

Comment: In Java I’d use `LocalDate.parse(endOfYear).plusDays(1).atStartOfDay(timeZoneId).toInstant().toEpochMilli()`. I am sure it can be expressed still more elegantly in Kotlin. It yields 1661986800000, which I think is the number you want. Except you wanted 1 second before the end of the day, which is ill-advised. The day does not end 1 second before it ends.